# how to enable content search within document library sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

We are starting our new sharepoint 2013 server.
We've created our first site, and made it a document management system, with a document library included.

How do I enable the library search to include results from documents that content, not just filename and metadata, match the search term.  In other words, if I want to search for "ice cream", I want to have all of the documents that have "ice cream" IN the document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used 2013 but from my understanding there isn't any special setup to get SharePoint to index the contents of a file.

The things you need to take in to account is the file types, there must be some form of IFilter so the content can be indexed and I believe OOTB all office ones are included. If you want PDF you will have to add the ifilter and there are loads of blogs explaining how to do this.

You will also need to have search setup and run a full crawl.

This [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4192bc48-40b4-442e-8a17-0c71f16a0f2a/search-for-content-within-a-file?forum=sharepointsearchprevious) explains how to set up a content source at a high level.

I hope this helps

Cheers

Truez

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to enterprice version cannt be done in standard version (you will miss content search web parts in standard version).